# Duplicity fails to run w/ python 2.3

Tags: redhat, duplicity

I tried running the latest code and went as far back as 0.6.07 and I keep getting the following error message when running duplicity. Any ideas how to fix? Tell me I dont have to upgrade to Python 2.4

```
[root@sierra duplicity]# duplicity
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 42, in ?
    from duplicity import commandline
File "/usr/lib64/python2.3/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 147, in ?
    class DupOption(optparse.Option):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.3/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 157, in DupOption
    ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS = optparse.Option.ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    AttributeError: class Option has no attribute 'ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS` is was added either in Python 2.4 or 2.5, so you'll have to go back to before duplicity used it. Going back to 0.5.x should be enough.

You could report a bug to the duplicity maintainers, since their web page says that Python 2.3 is supported. However they may just fix the issue by amending their requirements to 2.5.

Comment: yea i opened a "ticket" but have yet to hear from anyone.